# GeneratedValue with oracle and hibernate does not work

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I am facing an issue with the GeneratedValue annotation in my project with Oracle XE database. The value simply does not get generated - I keep getting the error when trying to insert rows in the table with the autogenerated  field.

```
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."T_VAPP"."VAPPID")"
```

The exact same code works with Derby or MySQL but I need to make it work with Oracle and it seems to ignore whatever I put in the generated field definition. I tried using GenerationType.TABLE, GenerationType.SEQUENCE but the same error persists. I also verified using Oracle SQL developer that none of the sequences defined in the code are being created. What do I miss here?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_vApp")
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(identifierColumn = "vAppId", identifierField = "id",  table = "T_vApp")
public class VLabApplication {



  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
  @Column(name = "vAppId" )
  private Long id;
```

Answer (score 2):

`GenerationType.AUTO` is correct --- this will ensure that your code works for oracle as well as mysql (without the need to change your code).  I use it like this and never had any problems.

Try removing the `@Roo` magic, generate setters/getters and see if this helps.  BTW, I usually annotate the getters. I don't think this is the problem, but you can always try if everything else fails.

My guess is some problem between roo and hibernate (I've never used nor read about roo, so it is really a *guess*).

Comment: Spring Roo just uses AspectJ to simplify your POJOs, such as generating all your get/set methods, the toString() method behind the scenes at compile time in AJ files.  There's other stuff it helps out with, but for the most part the Roo annotations just simplify your java code by removing the boilerplate stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it may be getting confused because you're telling it in two places what the identifier field is.  Plus you're telling it both with a @Table and the argument inside the @RooJpaActiveRecord annotation.   You should probably remove all the arguments from the @RooJpaActiveRecord annotation on the class.  Leave the @Id and @Column annotations on the class "id" member and the @Table annotation on the class.

Alternately, you may need to switch to a custom generator class that does the right thing based on which database.

Comment: Indeed - too many identifier definitions. I removed them as described but still the same error. Will try to create a fresh project just to test if something went sideways with the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You used `GenerationType.AUTO` instead of `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

Comment: AUTO for oracle will choose sequence generator (that's why it's called 'AUTO' ;) ).